# Remove CompleteWizardStep from CreateUserWizard?

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

I'm using an ASP control CreateUserWizard, and want to skip the page that says "user successfully created" along with the continue button. Is it possible to skip the CompleteWizardStep altogether?

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" FinishDestinationPageUrl="~/default.aspx">
        <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

I tried deleting the CompleteWizardStep altogether, but that doesn't work. I've tried adding a FinishDestinationPageURL to the CreateUserWizard as well, but that doesn't skip the success page confirmation.
Any help please?

Comment: Similar kind of question has been raised, so you will probably find the answer here **http://forums.asp.net/t/1149824.aspx/1**

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out, it does indeed skip the success confirmation page, but the user is not logged in after that (the AnonymousTemplate contents are displayed). I tried adding LoginCreatedUser="true" to the CreateUserWizard, but it does not log in automatically. Do you've an idea about this?

Comment: Yes, you just need to put this **LoginCreatedUser="True"** on your **CreateUserWizard**

Comment: yes, I did add it, but it does not log in automatically. I've to log in manually.

Comment: @codewarrior, have you found any solution??